# Find Class in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using AJAX to get the HTML DOM of another page and then storing it within a variable like this

```
var doc=xhr.responseText;
list=doc.getElementsByClassName("Cname");
```

Since the HTML is stored within the doc variable, I am using it to search for the class ,but it is throwing an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: doc.getElementsByClassName is not a function
```

How to fix this,that is how can I use that variable to search for the class stored in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying **[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)** on a string (`xhr.responseText` is a string) it will only work with dom object not with string.

So instead what you can do is, create a temporary dom element object using **[`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)** with the HTML content and get element inside.

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
var list = temp.getElementsByClassName("Cname");
```

```js
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = '<div class="Cname">a</div><div class="Cname1">a</div><div class="Cname">a</div>';
var list = temp.getElementsByClassName("Cname");

console.log(list);
```